# Date/time question asked on Android app

Tags: feature-request, bug, android-app

While browsing through the question list the questions themselves should contain the date/time the question was asked.
This feature is on desktop, but on the app it currently shows only edited times.

If this feature is already on the app, how can I see the time questions were asked?

Comment: Not exactly duplicate,when you open question there is no 
 mentioning time ques was asked? @shadow

Comment: You asked about question **list**, so we can sort the list by Newest - the thing is, it's just showing the last active time, so that other question already ask to show the time when it was asked - having this, you will have what you want as well.

Comment: Not convinced, see the difference how any ques is at web and how it renders at app